# Problem in navigation bar as Im not able to make it responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I made navigation which is working in html and css, but when I added to it react it didn't work and also, I'm Unable to add script in file also but it didn't work. I used a react helmet but it also didn't help me. In-fact when I added the bootstrap navbar it also didn't help me.
As I'm a facing problem when I make it to px below 800 it shows the hamburger menu option but when I click on it doesn't show the menu . One thing more when it always shows the home menu while on low px

this is my JSX code

```
 import React from 'react'
import './Heading.css'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Nav_items from './Nav_items'
import Nav_icons from './Nav_icons'
import useDocumentTitle from '../Document'
const Heading = () => {
    useDocumentTitle('Home')
    return (
       
        <div>
           <nav class="nav">
        <div class="nav-menu flex-row">
            <div class="nav-brand">
                <a href="/" class="text-gray" >NOOB-GEEKS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="toggle-collapse">
                <div class="toggle-icon"> 
                    <MenuIcon/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Nav_items/>
            
            </div>
           <Nav_icons/>
        </div>
    </nav>
   
        </div>
    )
   
    
}

export default Heading
```

this is my nav_items and nav_icons components

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav_items = () => {
    return (
        <div className="nav-items">
                    
                <NavLink activeClassName='nav-link' to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-link' to="/category">Category</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-link' to="/pages">Pages</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-link' to="/archives">Archives</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-link' to="/contact-us">Contact us</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-link' to="/log-in">Log-in/Sign-up</NavLink>
               
                </div>
    )
}

export default Nav_items
```

```
import React from 'react'
import FacebookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Facebook';
import InstagramIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Instagram';
import LinkedInIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LinkedIn';
import TwitterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Twitter';
import YouTubeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/YouTube';
const Nav_icons = () => {
    return (
        <div class="nav-social text-gray">
                <a href="" target='_blank' ><FacebookIcon/></a>
                <a href="" target='_blank'><InstagramIcon/></a>
                <a href="" target='_blank'><TwitterIcon/></a>
                <a href="" target='_blank'><LinkedInIcon/></a>
                <a href="" target='_blank'><YouTubeIcon/></a>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Nav_icons
```

this is my css code

```
.nav{
    background: white;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    height:0rem;
    min-height: 10vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height 1s ease-in-out ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.nav .nav-menu{

   justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav .toggle-collapse{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    width: 90%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
.nav .toggle-collapse .toggle-icon{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 1.7rem 0;
}

nav.toggle-collapse .toggle-icon div{
font-size: 1.4rem;
color: var(--text-gray);
}
.collapse{
    height: 30rem;
}
.nav .nav-items{
   
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav .nav-items .nav-link{
    padding: 1.6rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    position: relative;
    font-family: var(--Livvic);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.nav .nav-items .nav-link:hover{
    background-color: var(--midnight);
}
.nav .nav-items  .nav-link:hover{
  color:var(--white);
}

.nav .nav-brand {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    display: block;
    font-family: var(--Lexend);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
 }
.nav-social{
    padding: 1.4rem 0;
}
.nav-social a{
    padding: 0 .2rem;
}
.nav-social a:hover{
    color: #a1c4cf;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .nav .nav-menu, .nav .nav-items{
        flex-direction: column;

    }
    .nav .toggle-collapse{
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

this is my script which is I'm able to add it

```
$(document).ready(function() {`
    $nav = $('.nav');
    $toggleCollapse = $('.toggle-collapse');

    $toggleCollapse.click(function () {
        $nav.toggleClass('collapse');
        
    })
    //owl caraousel
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:3000 ,
        dots:false,
        nav:true,
        navText:[$('.owl-navigation .owl-nav-prev'),$('.owl-navigation  .owl-nav-next')]
    });
`});
```

Please help...As I again say that my problem is that my menu doesn't gets open when I click on it

Comment: You need to first, before working on your menu, decide what stack you want to work on. You want to use React or JQuery?  You want to use material-ui or bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle in React, you don't need jQuery. To add or remove class in React, you can use example as follows.

```
const Heading = () => {
    useDocumentTitle('Home')
    //create a open state (true / false)
    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false);

    //a simple toggle function that switches between true/false
    const toggle = () => setOpen(!open)
    return (
       
        <div>
           // here we add the 'collapse' class when it's false
           <nav class={`nav ${ open ? '' : 'collapse' }`}>
        <div class="nav-menu flex-row">
            <div class="nav-brand">
                <a href="/" class="text-gray" >NOOB-GEEKS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="toggle-collapse">
                //here u can use a onClick event to toggle true/false
                <div class="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle} > 
                    <MenuIcon/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Nav_items/>
            
            </div>
           <Nav_icons/>
        </div>
    </nav>
   
        </div>
    )
   
    
}

export default Heading
```

I don't use bootstrap so I am not aware where to add the specific classes, you should work out that part on your own.

Comment: Thanx bro...its working but there is one problem when I restore the screen Home nav is always showing

Comment: maybe you want to play around the state of `open`. I do not have your full source code to debug these issues.